# Linkedin SlideShare API "get_user_leads" 500 Internal Server Error and 410 Gone Error on apiexplorer.slideshare.net

Tags: linkedin-api

Looking for help from a Linkedin SlideShare engineer on the SlideShare API here. Very frustrated that I was told to use StackExchange after being kicked all over the place by them and now I can't post enough detail (personal account info would be needed and StackExchange is limiting me to 2 links in this message).

Anyhow, I’m trying to install the SlideShare-Marketo Connector (http://launchpoint.marketo.com/assets/Uploads/SlideShare-MarketoConnector-Guide.pdf) on to an ancillary server. I’ve uploaded the PHP files just fine.

The expected output from my page should be “X leads synced from SlideShare.” (where “X” is a number), but instead I get a blank page. I added some echos to see if I could figure out the last spot the code was executing to. I found that it’s getting hung up in SSUtil.php at this line in the function “get_userLeads”:

```
$data=$this->LeadXMLtoArray($this->get_data("get_user_leads","&username=$user&password=$pass&begin=$begin"));
```

From what I can tell though the issue isn’t really with this line but when the get_data function tries to get the data at this line:

```
$res=file_get_contents($this->apiurl.$call."?api_key=$this->key&ts=$ts&hash=$hash".$params);
```

I echoed the URL to the browser see what it was looking for:

```
http://www.slideshare.net/api/2/get_user_leads?api_key=XXXXXXXX&ts=XXXXXXXX&hash=XXXXXXXX&username=XXXXXXXX&password=XXXXXXXX&begin=201603311600
```

Obviously I can't make this link clickable here without give away a bunch of account information but when I click on a real version of the link I get a 500 Internal Server Error.

I used apiexplorer.slideshare.net (but now it seems SlideShare has taken this down in the last day) and the URL it’s using looks the same as what I’ve got above but has a slightly different result: 410 Gone Error. Any idea what’s going wrong?